How can I record with this old fashioned mono microphone?
I have this microphone that comes with a 3.5mm mono jack connector.
When I plug it in to my laptop or my phone it won't work, and I believe the "mono" part is the problem. What do I need to do?


You are likely plugging it into a port intended for headsets, not a mic.
You need an adapter which converts a headset port into a headphone port and a mic port.
Or plug it into some device which can use mics with that TS connector directly.

That's not a normal mic. That appears to be a magnetic coil pickup for a land-line phone handset. They don’t pick up sound directly. Instead, these are stuck onto the handset earpiece side, and pick up the electrical signal driving the speaker.
It won't do anything unless you have that kind of phone (a rare thing these days.) It certainly won't work for a cell phone. Otherwise, its output works like a dynamic, low-impedance mic, and its plug has the normal tip and ring configuration. So if you do actually have an old-school land-line handset it should work.
If you are intending to record a phone call, do be mindful of the laws governing this, especially locales (like California) that require 'all party consent' for recordings.
